# Simple loop does not paste ranges correctly

Tags: excel, vba, loops, paste

I have a simple loop that should copy ranges form three sheets and stack them on top of each other in another sheet. I define the ranges of each of the three sheets via a cell that counts rows in the Control Sheet.

I do not get an error message, however only the range of the first sheets gets pasted. I troubleshooted already to see if the loop is running until end and indeed it does. I cannot wrap my head around why only the range from the first sheets gets pasted in the final sheet.

```
Sub Loop()

Dim ws_Sheet As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
Dim lng_LastRow As Long, lng_LastColumn As Long, lng_LastRowSheet As Long
Dim rng_WorkRange As Range
Dim arrSht, i
Dim counter As Integer

arrSht = Array("a", "b", "c")

Set ws_Sheet = Worksheets("d")
ws_Sheet.Cells.ClearContents
counter = 1

For i = 0 To 2
    
    Set ws = Worksheets(arrSht(i))
    lng_LastRow = Worksheets("Control").Range("E" & counter).Value + 1
    lng_LastColumn = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    lng_LastRowSheet = ws_Sheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Set rng_WorkRange = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(lng_LastRow, lng_LastColumn))
    rng_WorkRange.Copy ws_Sheet.Range("A" & lng_LastRowSheet)
    counter = counter + 1
    
Next i
 
End Sub
```

Comment: Put a `Debug.Print arrSht(i), rng_WorkRange.Address, "to",  "A" & lng_LastRowSheet` after the `Set rng_WorkRange …` line and see in the immediate window if the ranges that you copy from each sheet is what you expect it to copy. You should get a line for each sheet showing the sheet name, which range to copy and where to paste. Add that information to your question, if you cannot solve the issue on your own with that information.

Comment: I recommend not to name your procedure `Loop` because this is a reserved keyword of the [Do...Loop statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/doloop-statement) in VBA.

Comment: You can use `i` instead of `counter`. What's `Control!E1:E3` all about? Is the code in the same workbook where these worksheets are located?

Comment: @VBasic2008 well, actually `i + 1` instead of `counter` to be precise. There is no `E0`.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ your comment helped a lot, indeed the areas are copied correctly  as follows
a       $A$1:$B$338   to            A1
b       $A$1:$B$91    to            A338
c   $A$1:$B$356   to            A428

but I still see only the rows up to 338 in my target sheet

Comment: I tested your code and it works fine except that you should use `lng_LastRowSheet = ws_Sheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1`. If `a`-data and `c`-data are the same, then maybe all data is copied, but if you have no data in column `A`,  `lng_LastRowSheet` remains the same for all worksheets hence each next worksheet overwrites the data leaving only the last data and possible remains of the previous data..

Answer (score 0):

The counter and the lng_lastRow variable is too messy.
I repaleced some code as follow：

```
Sub newLoop()

    Dim ws_Sheet As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim lng_LastRow As Long, lng_LastColumn As Long, lng_LastRowSheet As Long
    Dim rng_WorkRange As Range, rng_lastRange As Range
    Dim arrSht, i
    Dim counter As Integer
    
    arrSht = Array("a", "b", "c")
    Set ws_Sheet = Worksheets("Control")
    ws_Sheet.Cells.ClearContents
    
    For i = 0 To 2
        
        Set ws = Worksheets(arrSht(i))
        
        Set rng_lastRange = ws_Sheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
        
        lng_LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        lng_LastColumn = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Set rng_WorkRange = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(lng_LastRow, lng_LastColumn))
        
        rng_WorkRange.Copy rng_lastRange.Offset(1, 0)
    
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Why? What's the explanation for this? I don't see why this should solve anything. What has the paste destination row `lng_LastRowSheet` to do with the data in the `Control` sheet?

Comment: That's now entirely different from what the OP was doing.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is

```
lng_LastRowSheet = ws_Sheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

is the last used row (the last row that has data).
And then you use that to start pasting

```
rng_WorkRange.Copy ws_Sheet.Range("A" & lng_LastRowSheet)
```

so you overwrite the last row of data!

The next free row is `lng_LastRowSheet + 1` so you should paste there:

```
rng_WorkRange.Copy ws_Sheet.Range("A" & (lng_LastRowSheet + 1))
```

You can also see that in the debug data:

- a `$A$1:$B$338` to `A1`
- b `$A$1:$B$91` to `A338`
- c `$A$1:$B$356` to `A428`

`a` goes from A1:B338 but you start pasting `b` in `A338` so it overwrites the last row of `a`.

---

I gave it a test:

Created worksheet `Control` with data like
[image]

Then created worksheets `a`, `b` and `c` like
[image]
with data until row 500 so there is enough.

Then created an empty worksheet `d` for the output.

And used the following code. Note I have optimized it so it uses meaningful variable names, which is much easier to read, understand and debug.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CopyData()
    Dim SheetNames() As Variant
    SheetNames = Array("a", "b", "c")
    
    Dim wsDestination As Worksheet
    Set wsDestination = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("d")
    wsDestination.Cells.ClearContents
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To 2
        Dim wsSource As Worksheet
        Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetNames(i))
        
        Dim SourceLastRow As Long
        SourceLastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Control").Range("E" & i + 1).Value + 1
        
        Dim SourceLastColumn As Long
        SourceLastColumn = wsSource.Cells(1, wsSource.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        
        Dim DestinationFreeRow As Long
        DestinationFreeRow = wsDestination.Cells(wsDestination.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1  ' Last used row +1
        
        Dim SourceRange As Range
        Set SourceRange = wsSource.Range(wsSource.Cells(1, 1), wsSource.Cells(SourceLastRow, SourceLastColumn))
        SourceRange.Copy wsDestination.Range("A" & DestinationFreeRow)
    Next i
End Sub
```

And I get a perfect output like:
[image]

Note that in the output I have hidden some rows so you can see eveything is there. This code perfectly does what it is supposed to.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but this does not solve the issue that only the data from sheet a is pasted. The data from b and c is not even pasted!

Comment: @user10562005 with exact this code it's impossible. If you get those addresses out of the `Debug.Print` right before the copy then it would copy that too. Go through the code step by step using F8 and see if it runs the copy line. Check immediately after if it was pasted. Make sure there is no `On Error Resume Next` in your code.

Comment: @user10562005 see my test. The code works.

Answer (score 0):

### Stack Ranges (Vertically) From Multiple Worksheets

```vb
Sub StackRanges()

    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Source
    Dim sWorksheetNames() As Variant: sWorksheetNames = VBA.Array("a", "b", "c")
    
    ' Lookup (Source Last Row)?
    Dim lws As Worksheet: Set lws = wb.Worksheets("Control")
    Dim llrCell As Range: Set llrCell = lws.Range("E1")
    
    ' Destination
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("d")
    dws.UsedRange.ClearContents
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range("A1")
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet
    Dim srg As Range
    Dim slRow As Long
    Dim slColumn As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    ' Loop.
    For i = 0 To UBound(sWorksheetNames)
        
        Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sWorksheetNames(i))
        
        slRow = llrCell.Value + 1
        slColumn = sws.Cells(1, sws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Set srg = sws.Range("A1", sws.Cells(slRow, slColumn))
        
        srg.Copy dfCell
        ' If you only need to copy values (since you're using '.ClearContents'),
        ' instead, use the most efficient:
        'dfCell.Resize(srg.Rows.Count, srg.Columns.Count).Value = srg.Value
        
        Set llrCell = llrCell.Offset(1) ' next source last row lookup cell
        Set dfCell = dfCell.Offset(srg.Rows.Count) ' next first dest. cell
    
    Next i
     
End Sub
```